# How to make a thread wait for dataReceived event in another class

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, serial-port

I have a program which is creating packets of data and putting them into a queue with a separate thread checking the queue, if there is data, it sends it over a serial connection, otherwise it waits a little bit and checks again. The problem is the device I am sending to will get overwhelmed if I send too much data at a time and then won't respond. To fix this, I need to make my transmit thread wait until I have received an entire packet back from the device, so in the DataReceived event I check if I have received the entire packet, if so, it gets parsed and I would like to signal the transmit thread that it is ok to send another packet, otherwise, I want to wait for the rest of the data without signaling the transmit thread.

This is my transmit thread

```
Private Sub TxThread()
    While Not abortThread
        While (Not abortThread) AndAlso (txQueue.Count = 0)
            Thread.Sleep(500)
        End While

        mPort.SendCommand(txQueue.Dequeue())

        ''''
        '''' Wait for signal that entire packet received
        ''''

    End While
End Sub
```

This is my DataReceived

```
Private Sub mPort_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles mPort.DataReceived
    ' Checks to see if enough data has been received to check for the Preamble
    If mPort.BytesToRead >= 2 And mPort.IsOpen Then
        ' Stores the string received into the packet variable
        packet &= mPort.ReadExisting()

        ' Checks to see if the string starts with the correct preamble
        If packet.StartsWith(ToCharacters(CommandStringBuilder.PREAMBLE)) Then
            PreambleReceived()

        ElseIf packet.Contains(ToCharacters(CommandStringBuilder.PREAMBLE)) Then
            ' If the data doesn't start with a preamble but it contains one, then it cuts off everything before the preamble and 
            ' checks to see if it is long enough to get the length byte
            packet = packet.Remove(0, packet.IndexOf(ToCharacters(CommandStringBuilder.PREAMBLE)))
            ' If it is long enough, then it checks if it has the whole string using the length byte and the actual length
            PreambleReceived()
        Else
            ' If the data doesn't contain the preamble then discard the string and reset rxData
            packet = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PreambleReceived()
    ' If the string is long enough, check the length byte in the string
    If packet.Length > 8 Then
        ' Calls a function I defined to test the number of bytes I received vs the number of bytes I expect and returns the difference
        Dim bytesEqual As Byte = GetBytesReceived()

        ' If the length byte and the actual length match, then the entire string has been received and can be sent for parsing
        If bytesEqual = 0 Then

            ''''
            '''' Signal entire packet received
            ''''

            packet = ""

            ' If the actual length is greater than the bytes expected then check to see if the string contains another preamble
            ' and if it does, cut off and discard everything after and including the second preamble, if not then it discards the data
        ElseIf bytesEqual < 0 Then
            If packet.Substring(3).Contains(ToCharacters(CommandStringBuilder.PREAMBLE)) Then
                Dim receivedTextBuffer As String
                Dim startIndex As Integer = packet.IndexOf(ToCharacters(CommandStringBuilder.PREAMBLE), 3)

                ' Gets the index of the preamble starting at index 3 and removes it and everything after it
                receivedTextBuffer = packet.Substring(startIndex)
                packet = packet.Remove(startIndex)

                ''''
                '''' Signal entire packet received
                ''''

                packet = receivedTextBuffer
            Else
                ' If packet doesn't contain a preamble, then discard the data and reset
                packet = ""
            End If
            ' If the bytes expected > bytes received then exit without resetting anything and wait for more data
        End If
        ' If the length isn't long enough to see the length byte yet, exit without resetting anything and wait for more data
    End If
End Sub
```

It is worth noting that TxThread and the DataReceived with PreambleReceived are in separate classes so the mPort in TxThread is not the same as the mPort in DataReceived.

Comment: It is very buggy code, you'll have to throw it away.  Use Read() instead of ReadExisting(), google "state machine".

Comment: Sounds like a good job for AutoResetEvent [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @HansPassant could you elaborate a bit more on why the code is so buggy as well as reasoning for Read() instead of ReadExisting() please. Also, I looked up state machine and that seems to be what I'm looking for, thank you.

Comment: @HansPassant To be clear, you are implying that the state machine should be used in determining whether or not the data received is a whole packet or not, correct?